# How to insert list of tuples in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I've the following list

```
my_list = [("1", "A"), ("1", "B"), ("1","C")]
```

Now, I want to insert this data into SQL like:

| ID | ALPHA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |

P.S. Note: I know I can do it using for loop and can execute the query one at a time, but I want to execute the query only ones and want to have all the data into SQL i.e. **Insert data into SQL using multiple values.**

Edit: The length of the list may wary every time. So, I can't use the normal insert query for multiple values.

Comment: What is your question here? You've told us what you want, but what's stopping you getting that? What was your attempt? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Use a table value constructor

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The length of list always varies. So, I'm not able to insert it in sql using multiple values.

Comment: Why not? What stops you from building up the SQL statement in a loop so that it contains all the values from the list?

Comment: @Striezel It's just that it consumes much time to add it into another variable and then execute the query (using single value in insert query). So, trying another approach which is to use multiple values in insert query and then execute it once such as to reduce time.

Comment: @dough: I was not referring to single record in an insert query. What I meant was that you build up an SQL statement in a loop as a string and then send the whole big statement to the SQL database.

Comment: @Striezel I'm already doing that right now. I just want to know if there is any other way to do this task in more simple way and executing the query one time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert`:

```
insert into t (id, alpha)
    values (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C');
```

Note:  It seems strange to me to have an `id` column that is not unique.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff for answering, but I don't want to do it manually. Is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, ALFA)  
VALUES (1, 'A'),  
       (1, 'B'),  
       (1, 'C');
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but is there any other way!?

Comment: @dough: What are you hoping for? This does exact what you’re asking for. It’s hard to imagine a simpler syntax, and this maintains a single query. Obviously, you can still dynamically construct this query using a loop or join across your collection. But if you’re hoping to e.g., pass a Python array directly to a SQL query that’s not possible. (At least not directly; there are libraries that take Python data types and use them to dynamically generate SQL like this, but that’s a different question.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney No, I'm not trying to pass a python array directly. Your answer is valid but what can I do if the length of the list changes every time?. P.S. Note: I'm already using for loop and using insert query with single value.

Comment: @dough: I definitely wouldn’t recommend doing an insert per value. You can loop through your values to construct a query similar to what SQLPro proposed in this answer, and thus execute it as a single query.